# How to add value to field from file by using annotation?

Tags: java, maven, properties, configuration

I'm using maven project and i need to keep info in file in project it can be .properties/.config file I don't care but i need to have initalized field in this file like:

```
test.properties or test.config
test.name = Test
```

And next i want to use this value to initialize field in one of my method:

```
 public String sendName()  {
        @Value("${test.name}")
        String name;
        return name;
      }
```

but lombok annotation doesn't work, I'm using maven project it isn't Spring project, I know that one of the option is scan this file and take value who i want, but I hope that is another simpler option :)

Comment: Lombok's [`@Value` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

[image: My IDEA view]

I created by hand META-INF dir and add application.properties also when i click on "user.test" in annotation I was redirected to my properties file

Answer (score 0):

Use these two annotations:

```
@Inject // javax.inject.Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "name of the property", defaultValue = "if the property can't be found") // org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty
Field declaration;
```

The properties must be defined in the resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties file.
For example:

Java code:

```
@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "mysql.server.host", defaultValue = "localhost")
String remoteIP;
```

resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties file:

```
mysql.server.host=192.168.100.25
mysql.server.port=1111
```

Comment: I got null, did it exactly like you describe it but afterthat my field is null

Comment: The properties file should be on your classpath. Is it available?
This annotation first looks for System properties, then for JVM properties, then for properties files on classpath.

Comment: I added post look below

Comment: I have no idea whats going wron

Comment: And when i add defaultValue i stil got null

Comment: You forgot the @Inject annotation. You should use it both.

Comment: I tried with @Inject annotation and without in both trials the same result - null

Comment: Did you try naming the file microprofile-config.properties? 
ps. please check the imports as well

Comment: I try naming my properties file microprofile-config.properties and it also don't working, my pom.xml have I think rightly dependencies:
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.config</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-config-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>